# How to set cron on alternate Mondays in linux?

Tags: php, linux, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I want to execute cron on alternate Mondays, how can i set it in linux?
For example, if cron execute on **4th Sept 2017** then next will be
18th Sept 2017
2nd Oct 2017
16th Oct 2017
30th Oct 2017 and so on.
I refer [this document](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/02/16/run-cron-job-alternate-week-day/) but not sure that it is correct or not. If any one has an idea then let me know.

Comment: you should try it first if you found any difficulty then post the question

Comment: yes i will try many commands but does not run as required. so please post the solution.

Comment: In every situation, it is not possible to first try. If you are in development then you should know that client wants to changes on urgent basis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution would be to save somewhere (file, db,...) the last execution date and on every execution check if now is a right day for next execution. In this way you will be have more flexibillity than only with cronjob config.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that directly in Cron (probably not), but you for sure you can do it within your script. You can configure your cron task to run daily and then inside your script check if you must do anything or not. For that you can use any resource you need, code, a database to check if the task was run las monday... whatever